# Can a Paladin have more than one Smite working at the same time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

Can a Paladin have more than one [Smite Evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Smite-Evil-Su-) working at the same time, against different foes?

> Once per day, a paladin can call out to the powers of good to aid her in her struggle against evil. As a swift action, the paladin chooses one target within sight to smite. If this target is evil, the paladin adds her Cha bonus (if any) to her attack rolls and adds her paladin level to all damage rolls made against the target of her smite...
>
> The smite evil effect **remains until the target of the smite is dead or the next time the paladin rests** and regains her uses of this ability. At 4th level, and at every three levels thereafter, the paladin may smite evil one additional time per day...

Comment: can you add what smite is for those that don't quite know it off-hand?

Comment: I don't think someone who don't know what smite is would have any chance to be able to answer to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not stated that they can't in the core rules, so I would say that you can if your level is high enough to warrant multiple uses of Smite per day.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it kind of goes against the intent of Smiting, but there seems to be no rules reason why you can't. Much the same way you can smite a target and then switch to attack another target to get an AC boost. If Paizo didn't want players to be able to do this they would have specified.